# Reset Admin password for MacOS Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

In very much need of resetting admin password for MacOS Sierra.  Unfortunately the previous instructions for the Mac OS X does NOT work for my Macbook Air.  Please help!

Comment: Before we can even begin to help, we need to at least know what previous instructions didn't work & why they didn't work - what error did you get?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you edit this to explain what exact step / process failed you? We can either reopen this or fix the answer on the linked question. I could see where FileVault would interfere with older answers and be the reason you can’t reset the password or break into a Mac OS installation.